# GridView to excel after create send mail c#

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, sendmail

I want to send a .xlsx , first I created (It has html code in it) then I used a SMTP server to send it , it does attach the file but when I tried to open it " It says that the file is corrupted etc" any help?

Here is my code

```
    try
            {

            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            // Render grid view control.
            gvStock.RenderControl(htw);

            // Write the rendered content to a file.
            string renderedGridView = sw.ToString();
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test\ExportedFile.xls", renderedGridView);

           // File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test\ExportedFile.xls", p1);
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
            Response.Write(e.Message);
            }


            try
            {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("server");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@mail.com");
            mail.To.Add("db@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
            mail.Body = "mail with attachment";



            Attachment data = new Attachment("C:/test/ExportedFile.xls");
            mail.Attachments.Add(data);

            SmtpServer.Port = 25;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
          //  SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            }
            catch( Exception e) 
            {
            Response.Write(e.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Why is the path for the attachment different than the path where the file is written out to, in this example?

Comment: It´s same path , sorry we speak spanish here haha

Comment: is the file opened in Excel OK when you just browse to C:/test/ExportedFile.xls?

Comment: It does not open in Excel , displays the message "Excel cannot open the file "ExportedFile" because the file format or file extension is not valid.Verify that the file has not been corrupted and the file extension matches the format of the file.

Comment: I was reading some suggestions about this problem and it´s says that it is a Excel 2007 native configuration that does not allow you to open files that contains HTML

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to indicate the type of the attachment

Comment: Attachment data = new Attachment("C:/test/ExportedFile.xls");
            mail.Attachments.Add(data);

Comment: you havent set the mime type